# Any way to differentiate a building from a road in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

So if I have a general GPS Lat/Lng point, would it be possible to say, yes this point is in a building, or this point is on a road which a car could travel on?

Answer (score 4):

I do not think you can determine if a point is a road or a building purely with Google Maps data.  To do this I think you would need some additional data source.

However, you may be able to determine if a point is a road by using the [Snap point to street](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/snap.htm) technique.

I have re-written the technique to use Google Maps API v3 and added the Haversine function to tell you the distance (in km) between the original clicked point and the corresponding point in the nearest street.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Directions Simple</title>
<link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

rad = function(x) {return x*Math.PI/180;}

distHaversine = function(p1, p2) {
  var R = 6371; // earth's mean radius in km
  var dLat  = rad(p2.lat() - p1.lat());
  var dLong = rad(p2.lng() - p1.lng());

  var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
          Math.cos(rad(p1.lat())) * Math.cos(rad(p2.lat())) * Math.sin(dLong/2) * Math.sin(dLong/2);
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
  var d = R * c;

  return d.toFixed(3);
}

  var dirn = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var map;

  function initialize() {
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(53.7877, -2.9832);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom:15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: center
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
        // == When the user clicks on a the map, get directiobns from that point to itself ==
        var request = {
            origin: event.latLng,
            destination: event.latLng,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        dirn.route(request, function(response, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                if(response.routes && response.routes.length > 0){
                    route = response.routes[0];
                    if(route.overview_path && route.overview_path.length > 0){
                        pos = route.overview_path[0];
                        new google.maps.Marker({
                              position: pos,
                              map: map
                        });
                        alert(distHaversine(request.origin, pos));
                    }
                }
          }
        });
    });
  }




</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: I suppose this could be used in a way to determine if a point lies off the road. I imported a ton of gps points from OpenStreetMap that were just roads of a section I specified, but I know checking one point against the entire collection wouldn't be the best way.

Answer (score 2):

Best place to ask is https://gis.stackexchange.com/. Isn't it possible to figure out the road location from the layer which contains the roads? You'll be given the lat-long's of all road nodes. Unless it's a curved line, you can find if your lat-long point [lies on the road line](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080810130702AARKNVB). To convert [lat-long to cartesian](http://www.google.co.in/search?q=convert+lat+long+to+cartesian&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a), follow the link.

Comment: I've done something similar to this, but it is to determine the nearest road section given a GPS point. I'm trying to determine a way to tell if a car has deviated from the road and would have hit a building/landscape/rough terrain.

Comment: AFAIK, the only way to figure that out is to have a layer where buildings are marked as buildings (or similar bounded vectors). As for terrain, maps do provided bounded vectors which depict contours and various other terrain. If you can outsource your work, you can also get someone to manually create a layer and mark all the buildings in it, using AutoCAD (that's how maps are made) OR purchase maps or layers from sources who have already marked the buildings.

Comment: Any idea where to download/buy sets of GPS map data? I use OpenStreetMap a lot, but I'm curious to know how Google is creating its map views. They have to be getting their data from somewhere similar.

Comment: Apparently, Google spends billions to get map data from countries who have already done their geological survey. I saw this info on gis.stackexchange just two weeks back, but couldn't find it when I searched now. Your question is now asked here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4541/differentiating-a-building-from-a-road-on-a-map and help is on the way :) For now, maybey you'd want to look at http://www.census.gov/geo/www/tiger/tgrshp2010/tgrshp2010.html and http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/maps.html

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely take a look. This GIS stuff is getting more interesting every time I dig a little deeper.